# To update 2 charts in 1 time interval with same data

Tags: python, linechart, plotly-dash

I want to display 2 information which is air flow/sec and total air volume/sec in 2 different line chart. 
Air volume is the sum of prev airflow until current.

Below is my snippet.

```
...

dcc.Interval(
    id='interval-component',
    interval=PERIOD,  # in milliseconds
    n_intervals=0
)

...

@app.callback(
    Output(VOLUME_GRAPH, 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_volume_graph(n):
   f_per_sec = read_from_serial()

   # add with prev volume

...

@app.callback(
    Output(FLOW_GRAPH, 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_flow_graph(n):
    f_per_sec = read_from_serial()

...
```

Even though 2 registered callbacks use the same component-id (*id='interval-component'*) but actually there are 2 interval components which take sampling in a different time interval (it becomes 2 sampling values in 2t)

these are my print screen :

```
update_flow1 read_from_serial() y:14
update_volume1 read_from_serial() y:9
```

How can I show 1 sampling value in 1 sec interval inside update 2 line-charts or 2 different charts such as *line-chart* and *gauge chart*.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [callbacks post](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-invitation-to-interactive-visualization-with-dash-a200427ccce9) and [multiple output post](https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-outputs-in-dash-now-available/19437),

I get a conclusion which is read from serial once and updates 2 chart afterwards. It is possible for a callback to return 2 outputs.

this is the snippet code:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output(FLOW_GRAPH, 'figure'), Output('my-gauge', 'value')],
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)
def sampling_from_serial(n):
   ...


   return create_figure(data), flow_per_sec
```

Return values must have the same length (and type) with what is declared in output tag above. This feature only available in

> dash>0.39.0

Hopefully helps,